# String string = editText.getText().toString() give me string = null

Tags: string, android-studio, android-edittext, gettext, toast

Im using an EditText and I need get a String from the input of the EditText.
but every time I use `final EditText editText = (EditText) findViewByID(editText);
String string = editText.getText().toString()` and put it in a Toast `Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), string, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();` I get an empty Toast (null). any help?

Comment: You should tag language, and please note that `android-studio` tag says it is for IDE related questions and to use `android` for Android development questions.

Comment: where are you setting "editText"?  (it requires an ID)

Comment: here. I've added that line of code

Answer (score 0):

```
editText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, int arg1, int arg2, int arg3) {}

        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, int arg1, int arg2, int arg3) {}

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable arg0) {
        String string = editText.getText().toString();
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), string, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }
    });
```